# Visual Studio Code always asking for Bitbucket credentials

Tags: bitbucket

I started using Visual Studio Code, and I was trying to save my test project into Bitbucket, but Visual Studio Code is always asking for my Bitbucket credentials.

how can i solve this can some one help me please

[image]